# How do I change GNU Screen's meta-key to Cmd-a?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, macos

[GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)'s default meta-key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, which is really inconvenient for me because I frequently use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to move the cursor to the beginning or end of the line.

I'd prefer to change this to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> instead. I know this can be changed in my `.screenrc` file, but how do I encode the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key?

Comment: I assume you use Ctrl-a too often to get used to Ctrl-a (release ctrl) a to send Ctrl-a to the shell? - The problem with Cmnd-a is that it is the builtin for "Select All Text", which I am not sure how you will be able to undo.

Comment: @VxJasonxV hmm, I may be able to live with Ctrl-a,a but yeah I will probably mess it up too often. If Cmd-a won't work I'd settle for something like Shift-Cmd-a.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/142680/bash-vs-gnu-screen-replace-ctrl-a-with-ctrl-shift-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally think the command idea is a bad one, because it is intended to be the system key for app manipulation. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> appears to be unbound in the application menus, but I couldn't use any tricks to view what it's keycode may be. Thus, I would suggest <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>.

Having said that, if I understand the man page, and a resource on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=498675) on the topic, I believe you can change it to Shift-Ctrl-a either by using the -e flag (which I suggest you use to test with before putting it in your `~/.screenrc`).

You should be able to run `screen -e ^AA`. `^` is a common identifier for "Ctrl", and A means capital-a (shift + a), as opposed to a lowercase a, meaning the character by itself.

If that works, you should be able to add a line into your `~/.screenrc` that says: `escape ^AA` for it to automatically take place on any standard execution of `screen` just by itself.

Comment: I personnaly prefer `ctrl-@` shorcut, which is more convenient because one need  to only press two keys (`ctrl-@`) instead of three (`ctrl-shift-a`). Achieved with `escape  ^@@` in `~/.screenrc`. But it is a personnal preference ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I would also recommend trying out [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). It's kind of a "screen on steroids". It uses `C-b` as its prefix key, but even that is configurable. `tmux` allows you to easily configure every aspect of it. As per the `tmux` FAQ, you can change the prefix to `C-a` like this:

```
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix
```

Of course, since you wanted to get rid of `C-a` anyway, you may be happy with `C-b` instead.

You can easily install `tmux` if you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) installed, by running:

```
sudo port install tmux
```

Comment: Thanks, for the record I have long since switched to tmux.

Answer (score -1):

run 'cat' in a terminal and press cmd-a to see what characters it sends. You can then use that in your .screenrc

Comment: Welcome to the site! How does this differ from the other answer? If it does, can you please elaborate your answer a bit to make it easier to understand and follow?